# Source not found error given in debug mode when running a method in Java with a try/catch block

Tags: java, eclipse, try-catch

I'm working on a simple connect four game in Java and was making an attempt to use a try/catch block in my code that drops the player's disc into the game board. I edited some code to intentionally make it throw an error if the player tries to drop a disc in a full column, but when I made that change I get a 'Source Not Found' error in eclipse. Code below:

```
public void dropDisc(int column, int player, Scanner input) {
        //Method to drop a disc in the appropriate column of the game board.

        char disc;

        if(player == 1)
            disc = 'R';
        else
            disc = 'Y';

        column = (column * 2) + 1;  //Sets column to a blank space 

        try{
        //  for(int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        //  
        //      if (i == 5) {
        //          gameBoard[i][column] = disc;
        //          break;}
        //      else if (gameBoard[i + 1][column] == 'Y' || gameBoard[i + 1][column] == 'R') {
        //          gameBoard[i][column] = disc;
        //          break;}
        //  }
            for(int i = 5; i <= -1; i--) {

                if (gameBoard[i][column] == 'Y' || gameBoard[i][column] == 'R')
                    continue;
                else
                    gameBoard[i][column] = disc;
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Column full, please select another column.");
            column = input.nextInt();

            dropDisc(column, player, input);
        }
    }
```

If I comment out the second for loop and un-comment the first then the code works fine. I'm not sure why I get this Source Not Found error when I use the second version of the loop. Is there something obvious I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to identify the problem because you only posted some of your code. It would be easier to help you if you posted all of it. Having said that:

Other than missing a closing "}", your code compiles fine for me.

However this loop will never execute:

```
for(int i = 5; i <= -1; i--) {
```

You probably want something closer to this:

```
for(int i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
```

Comment: geez, I should just go stand in a corner and think about what I did. 
That simple inequality was what I was missing...

Comment: @LukeMorris I've made plenty of mistakes like that over the years.  :) .      If my answer was helpful, give me an up vote.